# Why am I getting a varriable not declared error?

Tags: java, variables

I keep getting this error `cannot find symbol - variable minDist` even though I know it has been declared and initialized. I feel like it's staring me straight in the face. Does anyone know why this is happening?

There's another class file that goes along with this, but I don't think the error is in there.

I get it on the third to last line, when I get to `minDist`, but if I remove `minDist` I also get it on `minCost` and `minMPG` as well.

```
public class AnnualFuelUseTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int sMiles1, sMiles2, sMiles3, sMiles4;
    int eMiles1, eMiles2, eMiles3, eMiles4;
    int[] dist = new int[4];
    double gals1, gals2, gals3, gals4;
    double[] MPG = new double[4];
    double price1, price2, price3, price4;
    double[] cost = new double[4];

    AnnualFuelUse[] fillUps = {new AnnualFuelUse(108438, 108725, 13.9, 2.98),
                               new AnnualFuelUse(108738, 109023, 15.3, 3.02),
                               new AnnualFuelUse(109023, 109232, 10.3, 3.05),
                               new AnnualFuelUse(109564, 109854, 13.1, 3.03)};

    for(int i = 0; i < fillUps.length; i++)
    {
        dist[i] = fillUps[i].calcDistance();
        MPG[i] = fillUps[i].calcMPG();
        cost[i] = fillUps[i].calcCost();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {
        int maxDist = 0;
        int minDist = dist[0];
        if (dist[i] > maxDist)
        {
            maxDist = dist[i];
        }
        if (dist[i] < minDist)
        {
            minDist = dist[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {
        double maxMPG = 0;
        double minMPG = MPG[0];
        if (MPG[i] > maxMPG)
        {
            maxMPG = MPG[i];
        }
        if (MPG[i] < minMPG)
        {
            minMPG = MPG[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++)
    {
        double maxCost = 0;
        double minCost = cost[0];
        if (cost[i] > maxCost)
        {
            maxCost = cost[i];
        }
        if (cost[i] < minCost)
        {
            minCost = dist[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s\n\n"
                       ,"Fill Up", "Days", "Start Miles", "End Miles"
                       ,"Distance", "Gallons Used", "MPG", "Price", "Cost");
    for(int i = 0; i < fillUps.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15.2f%15s%15.2f\n"
                          ,(i+1),(int)(1 + i *(i*1.1)), fillUps[i].getmySMiles()
                          ,fillUps[i].getmyEMiles(), dist[i]
                          ,fillUps[i].getmyGals(), MPG[i]
                          ,fillUps[i].getmyPrice(), cost[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("%10s%10s%30s%30s","Minimum",minDist,minMPG,minCost);
}                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response guys. I'm going off of a bad online highschool education, so about half of what I have learn is learned through experimentation.

Comment: [This will help you understand scope of variable](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 5):

You declared `minDist` inside of a `for` loop, so it only exists in there, and you cannot use it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring it within the scope of the for loop. You need to move the declaration of `int minDist` outside of that loop, to the same level that you're doing your printf.

Answer (score 2):

Always consider the scope in which you are declaring your variables because it determines the visibility of your variable.

You declare your variable within a for-block which is a scope. Then your are trying to reference these variable from outside the scope where you have declared them. That won't work.

```
public void foo () {

    while (someBool) {

        int someVariable = 0;

        someVariable = 1  // works because using and declaring takes place in the same scope.

    }

 someVariable = 2; // that won't work because variable is not existent in this scope.

}
```

Also consider that scopes can be hierarchically structured meaning a variable declared in some scope is also visible within all nested scopes:

```
public void foo () {

    while (someBool) {

        int aVariable = 0;

        if (anotherBool) {

            aVariable = 1; // works because this scope is a nested scope inside the scope where the variable has been declared.

        }
    }
}
```

You will find plenty of information about the well known concept of scopes which is used not only in C# but in most programming languages.

A point to start you research might be the MSDN documentation:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you declared `minDist` variable inside of loop so scope of that variable limited to that particular for loop.

so you cant access that variable outside.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, since you said

```
int minDist = dist[0];
```

in your **for** loop, it only exists in your  loop. For example,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = 0;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

would return an error as x isn't there outside of that loop. It's known as scope and is basically the different levels of invisibility. Think like inception, the movie - the people in the 2nd dream level know what the dream in the 1st level is, but the 1st level can't see the 2nd level. Therefore :

```
int x = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   x = 3; 
   int y = 10;
}
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
```

will print out 3 successfully but crash when it tries to print out y because simply put, they can't see y outside of the for loop.

To fix your problem: simply declare minDist outside of your loop, somewhere near the start and it should work.